# How can I create a table with Javascript and jQuery so that each cell is droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works fine to create a grid of divs:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // rows
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) { // columns
        var id = String.fromCharCode(65 + j) + i; // e.g., B1
        $('<div></div>').data('accepts', id).appendTo("#cardSlots").droppable({
            accept: '#cardPile div',
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: handleCardDrop
        }); 
    }
$("cardSlots").append("<br />");
}
```

...but when I resize the window, the divs sometimes slip on to the next line. I want a table with a fixed 6x10 size, but when I try to build a table instead of divs, I break the "droppable" property.

How can I rewrite the code above so that it creates a 6x10 html table where each cell is droppable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there were two things I needed to learn to do this right. The first is that appendTo is smart enough to know to put td inside tr, so this line is what allows me to create table rows on the fly:

`$('<tr></tr>').appendTo("#grid");`

The second is that I can identify the last (i.e., the most recently written) table row as follows:

`appendTo("#grid tr:last")`

So the end result (and it works perfectly, thanks Mike!) is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // rows
    $('<tr></tr>').appendTo("#grid");
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) { // columns
        var id = String.fromCharCode(65 + j) + i; // e.g., B1

        $('<td id="'+id+'"><div>' + id +'</div></td>').data('accepts', id).appendTo("#grid tr:last").droppable({
            accept: '#stack div',
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: handleCardDrop
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery UI's Sortable library:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

You can specify objects to be sortable just by a class or id name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I want to create a table onto which you can drag cards rather than a sortable list.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a `<table>`, and in each cell put a div with the droppable attached to it and `width:100%;height:100%;`

this will solve your problem